# How to add permissions for new MMS service

Tags: powershell, permissions, managed-metadata-service

I want to Add permissions for the new MMS service using powershell (all farm and application pool accounts) like below:

1. As Service administrator (Full control)
2. As Term store administrators (Full control)

How to add permissions using powershell?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try the [Set-SPMetadataServiceApplication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607738.aspx), What i am reading that you can set the Service administrator with the above command.

See this Example:

```
Set-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity "MetadataServiceApp1" -AdministratorAccount "contoso\username1" -FullAccessAccount "contoso\AppPoolAccount1,contoso\AppPoolAccount2" -RestrictedAccount "contoso\AppPoolAccount3,contoso\AppPoolAccount4,contoso\AppPoolAccount5" -ReadAccessAccount "contoso\AppPoolAccount6"
```

Here is for the [Term Store Administrator](http://Add%20/%20Remove%20Term%20Store%20Administrator%20and%20Changing%20Term%20Set%20Owner%20using%20PowerShell.)

```
$AdminName = "Domain/UserName"
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site "Path of your site"

    $termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Your Term Store Name"]


if($termStore -ne $null)

    {
# Removing all the existing TermStore Administrators
foreach($admin in $termStore.TermStoreAdministrators)

        {
$termStore.DeleteTermStoreAdministrator($admin.PrincipalName);

        }        



        #Adding new term Store Administrator
$termStore.AddTermStoreAdministrator($AdminName);


$group = $termStore.Groups["Your Group name"]

        if($group -ne $null)

        {     

            #Updating Owner of all the term set.                    
foreach($termSet in $group.TermSets) 

            {
$termSet.Owner = $AdminName;

            }

        }

    }


$termStore.CommitAll();
```